# C language-function that returns unsigned type for a big Fibonacci number (like the 89 element)

Tags: c, fibonacci, unsigned

I am new to C but doing some exercises (online and run to see if test passed) so this exercise is as follow

Requirements:

- write a function with return type unsigned and parameter unsigned (must use this type)
  -need to be able to get (return) the nth Fibonacci number for example 89 element (if first 3 elements are 0, 1, 1 the 89 element is 1,100,087,778,366,101,931).

Problem:

- saw some answers of using "unsigned long long" but the requirements don't allow using that type. Also can't use external libraries lime GMP

Need help what can I do?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned Fibonacci(unsigned numElement);

int main()
{
    unsigned element;
    element = Fibonacci(89);
    printf("%d\n",element);

    return 0;
}

unsigned Fibonacci(unsigned numElement){

    int fibonacciArr[100] = {0, 1};
    int i;

    for(i = 2; i < numElement; i++ ){
                fibonacciArr[i] = fibonacciArr[i-1] + fibonacciArr[i-2];
    }

    return fibonacciArr[numElement -1];
}
```

Get output:-2092787285 (i understand is out of range for unsigned int so is negative but not sure what to do to fix this)
Instead of expected out:1100087778366101931

-tried to use "unsigned long long" but don't fit exercise requirement
-change from first element to 1 (instead of 0 and worked) but thank you all

Comment: If your exercise asks you to return the 89th Fibonacci number in an 32 bit unsigned int then the exercise is not solvable.

Comment: One option is to implement a ‘large integer’ char array, where each digit in the integer is stored as an element in a character array.  Math gets a bit tricky, but certainly solvable.

Comment: You need to compile using compiler with 64bits unsigned numbers

Comment: The most sensible path appears to be: Clarify the requirements with the task assignor.

Comment: I'd simply forget this online crap (which one exactly BTW?) and learn C properly with some good book.

Comment: The edit of the expected value makes me think that that is not a verbatim quote of error message/requirements. Perhaps the 89 is supposed to be an example result (F11)?

Comment: If it's an online quiz maybe you could link to it? It might be valuable for others taking the same one to know that it is apparently broken.

Comment: And well you _could_ solve it using _very_ dirty hacks. `#define unsigned uint64_t`. Change printf to `%ld`/`%lld`. Change the variable inside the function from `int` to `uint64_t`. https://godbolt.org/z/jvjnWT19P  But I repeat, this is just pure evil, never do dirty hacks like that.

Comment: You don't need to use an array. You just need the previous two numbers, their sum, and a counter.

Comment: @user23291084 Save time and enable all warnings.  `printf("%d\n",element);` --> `printf("%u\n",element);`.  `int fibonacciArr[100] = {0, 1};` --> `unsigned long long fibonacciArr[100] = {0, 1};`

Comment: @user23291084  Rather than <tried use "unsinged long long" but don't fit exercise requirement>, review spelling and try again along with other fixes.

Comment: Please post a link to the exercise so that we don't guess what it requires, but just go there and look.

Answer (score 1):

Those requirements *as you understand them* are simply impossible, because, as you say, the correct result is too big for a 32-bit-unsigned-integer.

There are several ways to interpret the task you were given:

1. Unsigned does not literally mean 'unsigned int', it just means 'an unsigned integer type' and therefore 'unsigned long long' would be allowed.
2. Use 'unsigned', then claim your answer only works on C-implementations where 'unsigned' is 64bits as that is allowed by the standard. Insist that your answer is a correct C-program, even though none of the standard compilers will compile it correctly.
3. The 89 was an example of fibonacci numbers in general, not an example input to your function, and failing on 89 is acceptable.
4. An overflowed result is considered a correct result. In that case, you need to use `unsigned` everywhere, including your `int`-array. Overflowing an unsigned type is valid C, Overflowing a signed type is undefined behaviour.

Comment: 1. I tried using 'unsigned long long' but return test not passed due to return type.  2. and 3. is only exercise and write test not passed (no teacher)

Comment: @user23291084 Instructors make mistakes when creating exercises. Ask them what they mean with this task.

Comment: @user23291084 I added a fourth option that came to my mind

Answer (score 1):

With 3 changes, code is able to get the intended output of "1100087778366101931" using `unsigned Fibonacci(unsigned numElement);`.

Perhaps not likely what was intended yet,  *somehow* we need a 64-bit answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Add
#define unsigned unsigned long long

unsigned Fibonacci(unsigned numElement);

int main() {
  unsigned element;
  element = Fibonacci(89);
  // printf("%d\n",element);
  printf("%llu\n", element);
  return 0;
}

unsigned Fibonacci(unsigned numElement) {
  // int fibonacciArr[100] = {0, 1};
  unsigned fibonacciArr[100] = {0, 1};
  int i;

  for (i = 2; i < numElement; i++) {
    fibonacciArr[i] = fibonacciArr[i - 1] + fibonacciArr[i - 2];
  }
  return fibonacciArr[numElement - 1];
}
```